# Java ArrayList.toArray not working - returning reference of some kind

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm writing a program that involves reading data from a database and displaying it in a table in a GUI. I'm trying to convert a 2D ArrayList to a 2D array, by doing 1 column at a time, but when the list is converted, it's only returning a reference of some kind. I don't understand why this is and how I can fix it

The code I am trying is:

```
    System.out.println(columns);
    Object[] column0 = new String[15];
    column0 = columns.get(0).toArray();
    System.out.println(column0);
```

The arrayList in question, columns, is 
[[802018    , 800319    , 800319    , 800319    , 800319    , 800319    , 802112    , 802112    , 802112    , 802002    , 802002    , 802002    , 802003    , 802003    , 802013    , 802013    ], [5C92      , 1C19      , 1A33      , 1C36      , 1K71      , 5K71      , 1C05      , 1A92      , 5A92      , 1A14      , 1C84      , 5C84      , 1A85      , 5A85      , 1C81      , 5C81      ], [505, 1515, 1838, 2337, 515, 759, 805, 1500, 2048, 1053, 1303, 1900, 1101, 1640, 1203, 1755]]
and the column0 list is only showing as [Ljava.lang.Object;@436e852b

Answer (score 0):

The to toString on an array just prints out the reference to the array, which is what you are seeing. If you want to print out the contents of the array you can use `Arrays.toString()`

```
System.out.println(columns);
Object[] column0 = new String[15];
column0 = columns.get(0).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(column0));
```

Comment: Alternatively, just print `columns.get(0)`, since that is presumably some sort of Collection.